# Validating form PHP and sending to email

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate an email form, and have the valid results sent to my email.

From what i gather, the PHP goes at the top of my index page, and it is called to action with

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
```

From my form. When ever i try to submit my form, my page loads to a blank page saying it cant find

```
myurl.com/<?php%20echo%20htmlentities($_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]);?>
```

Where am i going wrong? Here is my PHP:

```
      <?php
    //my variables, email, emailerr set to 0
        $email = "";
        $emailErr = "";
        $subject = "Subscription";
        $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
        $location = "index.php";
        $sender = $recipient;
        $body .= "".$_REQUEST["$email"]." \n";

function test_input($data) {
           $data = trim($data);
           $data = stripslashes($data);
           $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
           return $data;
        }

        //check if field is empty
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Please enter a valid e-mail address.";
        } else {

          //send to function test_input($data) to validate format
          $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
          if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
              $emailErr = "Invalid e-mail format!";
        } else {

        //if successful mail subscription and return to main page 
        mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");

        header(Location: $location" );

        }
        ?>
```

and my HTML:

```
      //my form
            <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

    <div class="input">

    <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="NAME@EXAMPLE.COM">

<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span> 

<input type="submit" class="button" name="email_submit" id="submit" value="SEND">
```

Comment: It looks like your file is not a php file, so the code is rendered as if it were simple html.  Does the filename end in `.php`?  Also, if you want a form to post to itself, you can simply leave out the action attribute.

Comment: a blank action means self, so you could just use `action=''` how ever as its all one page you will still have to parse the other php

Comment: thank you for your replies, i renamed my index file to index.php and issue still occurs. I uses the action with htmlentities so i could protect against hacks, i assume leaving it blank still allows for those exploits?